# How to check all numbers from a Series in SQL

Tags: sql

How to check all numbers from a Series in SQL

```
CityFrom   CityTo   AwbnoFrom   AwbNoTo

Delhi       Mumbai    10          13
delhi       Patna     35          38
Delhi       Pune      39          41
```

I want to output like this way:-

```
CityFrom    CityTo    TotalAwbNo

Delhi        Mumbai      10
Delhi        Mumbai      11
Delhi        Mumbai      12
Delhi        Mumbai      13
Delhi        Patna       35
Delhi        Patna       36
Delhi        Patna       37
Delhi        Patna       38
Delhi        Pune        39
Delhi        Pune        40
Delhi        Pune        41
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Answer (score 2):

If, you are working with SQL Server, then recursive `CTE` might useful.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT CityFrom, CityTo, AwbnoFrom,  AwbNoTo from table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CityFrom, CityTo, AwbnoFrom+1, AwbNoTo
    FROM cte
    WHERE AwbnoFrom < AwbNoTo
)

SELECT CityFrom, CityTo, AwbnoFrom AS TotalAwbNo 
FROM cte
ORDER BY CityFrom, CityTo, AwbnoFrom
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```